# pip не распознано как имя командлета

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Не могу установить discord.py .При попытке появляется вот это. Что нужном в таком случае для установки?

Заранее спасибо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы установили Python то вероятнее всего нужно просто запустить установку python-а опять и в конце нажать на кнопку "DISABLE PATH LIMIT",  выбрать нужно именно кастомную установку, а так же нужно установить галочку при установке "ADD TO PATH", и желательно установить для всех пользователей. Желательно так же отказаться от русских названий папок т.к из-за особенностей кодировки windows это может стать проблемой.

Comment: Спасибо 
Всё получилось!

Comment: Было бы приятно если бы вы пометили мой ответ как верный.

Answer (score 0):

Возможные решения проблемы:

1. Исключить директории с русскими названиями по пути проекта
2. При установке `Python` обязательно добавить его в PATH. Поставив галочку на пункте `ADD TO PATH`.
3. В конце установки `Python` отключить PATH лимит. Нужно нажать на кнопку `DISABLE PATH LIMIT`